# WSO2 API Management resource owner authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

It is possible to configure WSO2 API Manager to authenticate the user(resource owner) without IdentityServer?

For example need to return login form to authenticate the resource owner via Active Directory or other LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Manager has the same user authentication than all other WSO2 products using configured userstore.

Effectively you need to configure you userstore in the `repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` configuration

Comment: Thanks for response. I configure the AD as a tenant. But when I try to grant with the AD user, I get an access denied for that API. Are there any special permissions for AD users in the API manager?

Comment: if you set up a tenent, you may need to to login as `USERSTORE\username@tenant.domain` (or maybe it's enough `username@tenant.domain` )